# Hosting a WCF service in Azure WebRole with high availability

Tags: wcf, iis, azure

I am in a situation where I need a WCF service highly available on an Azure WebRole. There is, however a slight problem, because this service shall process requests which need a lot of data (3GB) to be loaded from Blob Storage. This data only needs to be loaded once the service starts up! So, what happens is that in the constructor of the service I am loading this data (which takes about 2 minutes). Every request to the service only takes ~100 milliseconds.

The first problem I have is that the constructor of the service only gets called on the first request. So the first person to use this service has to wait for 2 minutes, which is really annoying.

The second problem is that every other day (sometimes half a week) the service has to load that data again. So I suppose the service class has been disposed? Therefore people using the service again have to wait for 2 minutes in which the service is not responsible.

I do not know why this is happening and how to stop it from happening. My service is in InstanceContextMode.Single and ConcurrencyMode.Multiple.

Any ideas are highly appreciated!!

Comment: Does the gigabyte piece of data change? How often does it change?

Comment: The data may only change once a month, and only with a new update to the entire service, so in general, it won't really change much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the magic piece of data doesn't change often you should download it from inside `OnStart()` so that requests are not dispatched to the role instance until `OnStart()` returns. About two minutes extra work in `OnStart()` is not very nice but it might be tolerable especially since the users will not notice the delay anymore.

Comment: Isn't the OnStart() method of the WebRole inside a different AppDomain than the service?

Comment: @Christian: Em... Who cares? You load the data to the disk and then call the WCF service (call to "localhost") to make it load the stuff from the disk - all from inside `OnStart()`.

Comment: Hm, I will give it a go, but then it would still need to be loaded from disk on the first call of the first client, which may also take seconds

Comment: @Christian: Not if you send a request to "self". If there's some kind of "idle timeout" you can send requests periodically from inside `Run()`.

Comment: this may actually be the solution, in the OnStart() method I just need to call the service itself on localhost and it will take care of initializing... I'll try it out

Comment: This works! Great! Thank you! - I now implemented a method "InitializeService()" which is also exposed through WCF and the WebRole just calls that method once upon OnStart()

Comment: @Christian: Maybe you need to make that method "local only" so that it can't be called from outside otherwise some a-hole can easily DOS your service.

Comment: do you know how to make it local only?

Comment: @Christian: If it were inside ASP.NET you could check `HttpRequest.IsLocal`. I guess there's something similar in WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Loading 3GB of data into the worker role process probably isn't a good idea. You mention "High Availability" so What happens when you want to spin up multiple worker roles side by side to load-balance your requests. Each of those workers needs to host that data. Plus in a multi-instance environment, Azure reserves the right to spin down your services and move them around and spin them back up for resource allocation purposes among other things.

Have you considered using the App Fabric/Windows Azure Caching to host your data ?

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/caching/

You could load it into cache with a seperate worker role and refresh it as required at some known time when server load is low.

And then you could have all your webservice worker roles query that data in the cache as needed.

Comment: Windows Azure Caching will not work, because the 3GB of data need to be in memory of each service role. This is a must-have, because contacting the Caching services takes too long.

Comment: @Christian - I believe Eoin is talking about running cache within a set of role instances in your deployment (a co-located cache), which should offer very low latency (it's between VMs in the same service). There's also a cache *service* which is external to your deployment and has more latency since it's a separate service.

Comment: Aye. both options are available. (it's hard to know from the post whether you need access to all 3 gb of data simultaneously for each request / or just a small subset which could be obtained by key). If the azure hosted cache (pricing above) isn't suitable you could spin up your own cache within a set of roles, or alternatively spin up a win2k12 vm and host your own app fabric cache as david suggests. just loading 3GB of data in the constructor or even role_start of a wcf web service role smells like bad design to me.